# Execute more submit in sequence in same page

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I have that code and it work fine!

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $_SESSION['submit1']=true;
}

if(@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit1']) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit1']=false;
        include_once('./my3page.php');
       }
       include_once('./searchname.php');
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./searchform.php');
}
```

Now i would like to add other submit session (because i have 2 search type)

**WHAT I TRIED**

index.php

```
session_start();
 //---------------FIRST SEARCH TYPE--------------------------------
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $_SESSION['submit1']=true;
}

if(@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit1']) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit1']=false;
        include_once('./my3page.php');
       }
       include_once('./searchname.php');//PAGE WITH SUBMIT3
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
}   

//---------------SECOND SEARCH TYPE------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $_SESSION['submit2']=true;
}

if(@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit2']) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit4'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
        $_SESSION['submit2']=false;
        include_once('./my3page.php');
       }
       include_once('./searchdate.php');//PAGE WITH SUBMIT4
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} 

//------------------------
else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./searchform.php'); //FIRST PAGE THAT CONTAINS 2 FORM AND 2 SUBMIT BUTTONS, AS I WROTE BELOW
}
```

searchform.php

```
   IF YOU SEE THIS IS SEARCHFORM
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>" />
    <input name="submit1" type="submit" value="Search1"/></td>
    </form>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>" />
    <input name="submit2" type="submit" value="Search2"/>
    </form>
```

token.php

```
$form_token = uniqid();
$_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
```

searchdate.php

```
IF YOU SEE THIS IS SEARCHDATE
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>">
<input name="submit4" type="submit" value="OK2"/>
```

searchname.php

```
IF YOU SEE THIS IS SEARCHNAME
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>"><br>
<input align="left" name="submit3" type="submit" value="OK1"/>
```

my3page.php

```
MY3PAGE reached
```

**PROBLEMS**

- If i press submit1 it execute also include_once('./searchdate.php');
- If i press submit2 it execute also include_once('./searchform.php');

Why?

Comment: I'm unable to figure out what your trying to achieve especially with session. What and where is your submit3 and submit4 ?

Comment: i wrote //PAGE WITH SUBMIT3 and //PAGE WITH SUBMIT4.I explain: searchform.php is a page with 2 search form with submit1 and submit2.If i press submit1 i need to show searchname.php while if i press submit2 i need to show searchdate.php.My3page is a page with 2 query(UPDATE) with results. I would like to avoid double insertions and so i'm using a token.I don't need to renew token in searchname/searchdate because they are only a SELECT query and so there aren't problem with double insertion. Users can choose to use searchname or searchdate.Session starts in searchform and ends in last submit3or4

Comment: The first code that i posted is single search type (if user choose only submit1 for exampel) and it work fine! Now i would like to add the second search type! But what i tried return me 2 problems (as i wrote before) and i can't reach my3page (in both cases)

Comment: can u show the page which contains submit3 and submit4 ?

Comment: When you press submit1 the session $_SESSION['submit1'] is set true. And it is set true until you press $_POST['submit3']. So If you press whatever button after pressing submit 1 " && @$_SESSION['submit1'] " this is always true.

Comment: i update the first post, please see, if i press submit1 submit must be true, if i press submit2 it must be true... and they must be unset with respectively submit3 or submit4

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. You seach form will now included only if submit1 and and submit2 not pressed. 
Comments added in appropriate places.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', false);
?><!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ricerca</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        session_start();
        if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
            $_SESSION['submit1'] = true;
            $_SESSION['submit2'] = false; //you can remove if this is not needed.
        }
        if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
            $_SESSION['submit2'] = true;
            $_SESSION['submit1'] = false; //you can remove if this is not needed.
        }

        //---------------FIRST SEARCH TYPE--------------------------------
        if (@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit1']) {
            if ($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
                if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {
                    unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                    $_SESSION['submit1'] = false;
                    include_once('./my3page.php');
                }
                else { //include only if not submit 3 not pressed.
                    include_once('./searchname.php'); //PAGE WITH SUBMIT3
                }
            } else {
                header("location: ./index.php");
            }
        }else if (@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit2']) {
            if ($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
                if (isset($_POST['submit4'])) {
                    unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                    $_SESSION['submit2'] = false;
                    include_once('./my3page.php');
                }
                else { //include only if not submit4 not pressed.
                    include_once('./searchdate.php'); //PAGE WITH SUBMIT4
                }
            } else {
                header("location: ./index.php");
            }
        }
        //Include only if both submit1 and submit2 not pressed.
        else {
            include_once('./token.php');
            include_once('./searchform.php'); //FIRST PAGE THAT CONTAINS 2 FORM AND 2 SUBMIT BUTTONS, AS I WROTE ABOVE, THAT I SEE WHEN I PRESS SUBMIT1 (WHY?)
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing... it return same error... If i press submit 1 i see searchform (correctly) but also searchname.php (error) and after if i press submit3 i see mypage3 (correctly) but also searchform again (error). If i press submit2 i see only searchdate (correctly) but after when i press submit4 i see my3page (corretly) but also searchdate.php (error). Before i wrote an error..i can reach my3page in both cases

Comment: Why i must try that? I think it's useless because if i press submit1 $_SESSION['submit2']=false; is already false. I'm wrong?

Comment: Infact if i use your code nothing happen! It's everytime the same :(. ATTENTION: READ AGAIN FIRST COMMENT TO THIS POST: if i press submit1 i see SEARCHFORM not SEARCHNAME and if i press submit2 i firstly see only SEARCHDATE(correctly) but after, when i press submit4, i see my3page and SEARCHDATE is loaded again. thanks

Comment: Probably the real problem is in the use of { }. But i don't know where!

Comment: My understanding is given in answer can u confirm that is you are working for ?

Comment: so i understand now i put it in first post one moment

Comment: 1. first display index page with submit1 and submit 2.
2. then click submit1 or submit 2.
3. if submit1, then show searchname.php (submit3) only.
4. if summit2, then show searchdate.php (submit4) only.

is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, is correct. but if i press submit2 i have an error only in last page (my3page)!

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Can u please tell me what was that mistake?

Comment: Sorry, before i did a mistake with ctrl+c ctrl+v. Your code is right! i remove             $_SESSION['submit1'] = false; and $_SESSION['submit2'] = false; because it work without them. THANKS A LOT!